# How to search in NSArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, xcode4.2

I am having an array like fallowing,

```
NSArray*array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1.1 something", @"1.2 something else", @"1.3 out of left field", @"1.4 yet another!", nil];
```

Now,i am having the string like fallowing,

```
NSString*str = @"1.3";
```

Now i will send the str .Then it needs to find that str in array and it need to return the index of object where that text found.Means i need index 2 has to come as output.Can anyone share the code please.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I changed your dataset to reflect what I think you mean to ask more precisely. Your old dataset was throwing people off because the numbers were the only things different between the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
NSString *searchString = [str stringByAppendingFormat: @" problem%@", [str substringFromIndex: 2]];
NSUInteger index = [array indexOfObject: searchString];
```

Or (because you somehow like oneliners):

```
[array indexOfObject: [[array filteredArrayUsingPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF beginswith %@", str]] objectAtIndex: 0]];
```

Comment: I wont change anything.i am having same array and same string.And i will send 1.3 onlyyyyyyyyy.then i want index.I think now you got the thing.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example using blocks, notice the method: `hasPrefix:`

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1.1 problem1", @"1.2 problem2", @"1.3 problem3", @"1.4 problem4", nil];
NSString *str = @"1.3";

NSUInteger index = [array indexOfObjectPassingTest:
                    ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                        return [obj hasPrefix:str];
                    }];

NSLog(@"index: %lu", index);
```

NSLog output:

```
index: 2
```

Answer (score 2):

First a comment,

```
NSString *str = 1.3;
```

does not create an `NSString` object. You should instead have

```
NSString *str = @"1.3";
```

To search the `NSArray`, you will either have to change the string to the **exact** string in the array or search the `NSString` as well. For the former, simply do

```
float num = 1.3;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f problem%d",num,(num*10)%10];

[array indexOfObject:str];
```

You can get fancier using `NSPredicate`s as well.

Comment: Nice one.But if i sent completestring nothing matter there is direct method indexOfObject .But i will send only 1.3 .Just read the question again.Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to enumerate through values of array and check substrings:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1.1 something", @"1.2 something else", @"1.3 out of left field", @"1.4 yet another!", nil];
NSString *str = @"1.33";
int i = -1;
int index = -1;
for (NSString *arrayString in array) {
    i++;
    if ([arrayString rangeOfString: str].location != NSNotFound) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
NSLog(@"Index: %d", index);
```

Not optimal but will work.